# asignar atributos de validacion a html date con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas tardes ¿Alguien sabe como aplicar correctamente esta función? 
Encontré un código en este mismo lugar que me permitía ingresar un valor de "today" como minimo para un date en HTML

```
<input id="datefield" type='date' min='1899-01-01' max='2000-13-13'></input>
```

el detalle es que cree otro date, pero esta vez quiero que este date tenga como parametro minimo la fecha asignada al primer date

```
<input id="datefield1" type='date' min='1899-01-01' max='2000-13-13'></input>
```

y este es mi javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){ 
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //enero es 0
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 


today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
/* hasta aquí todo sirve para asignar a today la fecha de hoy*/
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);
/* se asigna la fecha minima para el atributo datafield*/
var x = document.getElementById("datefield").value; // aqui trato de obtener la fecha de datafield
document.getElementById("datefield1").setAttribute("min", x); //y aqui trato de asignar la fecha almacenada en x como fecha minima
}
</script>
```

de igual manera adjunto el fiddle para que vean funcionando mi avance.
https://jsfiddle.net/iscortex/dae4y126/2226/

saludos cordiales!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes usar un event listener sobre el datefield,asi cada vez que el datefield pierda el focus, se agregara el atributo min del datefield, al datefield1.

```
  window.onload = function(){ 
   var today = new Date();
   var dd = today.getDate();
   var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //enero es 0
   var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
   if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    }    


   today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
   /* hasta aquí todo sirve para asignar a today la fecha de hoy*/
   document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);
   /* se asigna la fecha minima para el atributo datafield*/




  document.getElementById("datefield").addEventListener('focusout',function(){
        var x = document.getElementById("datefield").value;

        document.getElementById("datefield1").setAttribute("min", x); 
    });

}
```

Comment: excelente!!! muchas gracias