# Input date habilitar días a partir de la fecha de inicio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente estoy trabajando con 2 input tipo `date`, entonces me gustaría que al momento de seleccionar mi fecha de inicio (puede ser cualquiera incluso de años pasados, es libre) en mi campo de fecha fin únicamente se habiliten los días a partir de la fecha de inicio (los días pasados no):

```
<label>inicio <input type="date" id="start" name="start" value=""></label>
<label>fin <input type="date" id="start1" name="start1" value=""></label>
```

¿Alguna idea en JavaScript  o jQuery?

Actualmente cuento con este codigo pero lo unico que hace es que a la fecha fin , bloquea dias pasados, pero me gustaria que al momento de seleccionar la fecha de inicio en automatico habilite los dias apartir de esa fecha en el campo fecha fin(no pasados)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
var fecha = new Date();
var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
var dia = fecha.getDate();
var _mes = fecha.getMonth(); //viene con valores de 0 al 11
_mes = _mes + 1; //ahora lo tienes de 1 al 12
if (_mes < 10) //ahora le agregas un 0 para el formato date
{
  var mes = "0" + _mes;
} else {
  var mes = _mes.toString;
}

   document.getElementById("start1").min = anio + '-' + mes + '-' + dia;
});
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [asignar atributos de validacion a html date con javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/220671/asignar-atributos-de-validacion-a-html-date-con-javascript). PD: Los inputs deberían tener diferentes `id`

Comment: si claro ya lo corregi, pero sigo pensando en una solucion

Comment: creo que no es duplicada

Comment: Si que es duplicda